# PageableListView Not rendering my data as required

Tags: wicket, html, html-rendering, wicketstuff

i am working on wicket, where i am supposed to show my data's under

```
<tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Single Player Score</td>
   <td>Double Player Score</td>
   <td>Total Score</td>
</tr>
<tr wicket:id="data">
   <td wicket:id="name"></td>
   <td wicket:id="singlePlayerScore"></td>
   <td wicket:id="doublePlayerScore"></td>
   <td wicket:id="totalScore"></td>
</tr>
```

My Player model class is as:
Player class with attributes singlePlayerScore, doublePlayerScore(), name with getter and setter and also a list data obtained from database.

Data from SQLQuery is as;

```
name        score    gamemode
  A           200       singlePlayerMode 
  A           100       doublePLayerMode
  B           400       singlePlayerMode 
  B           300       doublePLayerMode
dataList == player.getScoreList();
```

My PageableListView is as:

```
     final PageableListView listView = new PageableListView("data",dataList,10){
@Override
protected void populateItem(Item item){
    player = (Player)item.getModelObject();
    item.add(Label("name",player.getName()));
    item.add(Label("singlePlayerScore",player.getName()));
    item.add(Label("doublePlayerScore",player.getName()));
    item.add(Label("totalScore",String.valueOf(player.getSinglePlayerScore()+player.getDoublePlayerScore())));
  }
}
```

My Problem is as:
What view i get is as:

```
Name         single Player Score               Double Player Score       Total Score
A              0                                  100                      100
A              200                                 0                       200
B              0                                   300                     300
B              400                                  0                      400
```

How do i achieve below view on my webpage?

```
 Name         single Player Score               Double Player Score       Total Score
    A              200                                  100                     300
    B              400                                  300                     700
```

Please help me as to why is this happening?
I guess my list has size four that's one reason why as to it is rendering the view?
So what can i do to get as require rendering view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your SQL query to something like this:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    sum(singleplayerscore), 
    sum(doubleplayerscore), 
    (sum(singleplayerscore) + sum(doubleplayerscore)) AS totalscore 
FROM `scorelist` GROUP BY name
```

This way the scores adds up for each player (column name) and creates an additional column, totalscore, with the total score.

Comment: O You took me out from HELL. Thanks Mate.